# How do I copy files based on a list, into their corresponding folders which are also created based on a list?

Tags: c, powershell, batch-file, cmd, scripting

So, I'm completely new to scripting and batch files.

I'm looking to copy files based on a list of the files to copy. I have a text file for the list of files to copy and I want the script to copy all these files line by line from a source directory.

For example I have over a 1000 files to copy, and there are 3 files for each folder I want to create and put them into. Below is an example of how the files names are formatted:

```
file3_AB12_autoc.pdf
file3_AB12.jpeg
file1_AB12.png

file3_CD34_autoc.pdf
file3_CD34.jpeg
file1_CD34.png

...etc...
```

Once these are copied, I want to move them into folders that I created using a text file and the command:

```
FOR /F %i in (folders_list.txt) do md %i
```

Now, with my script, I want to move the files it copies into their corresponding folders. Basically if the file name contains the folder name, then they should move into the folder. For example:

```
C:\AB12                          THIS FOLDER SHOULD HAVE ALL THE FOLLOWING FILES
     file3_AB12.jpeg
     file3_AB12_autoc.pdf
     file1_AB12.png

C:\CD34                          THIS FOLDER SHOULD HAVE ALL THE FOLLOWING FILES
     file3_CD34.jpeg
     file3_CD34_autoc.pdf
     file1_CD34.png
```

---

I have looked up other similar questions but nothing seems to work for what I want to do. I believe the links below are useful but I do not know how to put them together.

[How do I copy files into folders based on the file containing the folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52956840/how-do-i-copy-files-into-folders-based-on-the-file-containing-the-folder-name)

[Copy files based on a list stored in .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906622/copy-files-based-on-a-list-stored-in-txt-file)

Comment: Hi there.  I notice this question is tagged with the C language.  Are you looking for a solution in C?

Comment: That sounds ambiguous to me, you want to copy files from a list and **then move** them? To a directory build from part of the file name/another list? If the 1st list is in fact something like a dir output, it would be much easier to process the dir with a `for /f` and another one parsing the part bewtween the underscore(s) and the dot for a batch solution. Or similarly for powershell.

Comment: No point in having a list of directories.  If the folder name is part of the filename, the filename can be parsed to get the directory name.

Comment: The hardest part would be the regex, the rest you could do with PowerShell fairly easily with a `Get-Content` and a `Foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, Move-Item will move the files. Then you just need regular expressions to determine the path and new file name, similar to:

```
$txt = "file3_AB12_autoc.pdf
file3_AB12.jpeg
file1_AB12.png
file3_CD34_autoc.pdf
file3_CD34.jpeg
file1_CD34.png
badfilename.txt"

foreach ($orig_file in $txt -split '\r\n') {

    if ( $orig_file -match '^([^_]*)_([^_.]*)(.*)\.(.*)$' ) {
        $dir = $matches[2]
        $new_file = '{0}{1}.{2}' -f $matches[1], $matches[3], $matches[4]

        'Moving {0} to {1}\{2}' -f $orig_file, $dir, $new_file

        Move-Item -Path $orig_file -Destination ('{0}\{1}' -f $dir, $new_file)

    }
    else {
        '{0} not processed' -f $orig_file        
    }

}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding `if (!(Test-Path -Path $dir -PathType Container)) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $dir }` above the `Move-Item` comand to ensure the output directory is created if it does not exist.